# keep corporate app alive in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am developing a corporate app that will be publish on an internal store.
The app is just supposed to keep in memory some credentials but I can't store them on the device for security reasons.

I want the app to stay in background as long as possible but I don't know what is the best solution knowing that I won't have to publish the app in the AppStore.

I read about the option in plist `Required background modes`, but I don't know which option is the most efficient for my situation.

Comment: The app doesn't have to stay active in background in order to keep the credentials in RAM. Beyond this, the OS will kill the app whenever it needs to make RAM for active apps no matter what you do short of jailbreaking, and even then I have no idea.

Comment: What you want to do is impossible. Use the keychain, or always fetch them from a website.

Comment: @nhgrif I accept that the app is killed if the phone need more memory, on new corporate iPhone it shouldn't be that often :). But if the app is in background for a day, when I launch it again I don't come back on the current page but on the launch page. I didn't checked but are you saying my variables could still have my credentials ?

Comment: @nhgrif My question could be ask like this: how can I keep my variable in RAM after after one day in background ?

Comment: Apple has file-based encryption and/or Keychain. There is absolutely no need to run app infinitely and if you think nobody can steal your passwords from RAM, you are fooling yourself.

Answer (score 2):

**Firstly**, you don't need to keep running app in background, **second** you can store "those [secret] credentials" in `keychain` store with some encrypted format, `SHA1` or `MD5` or any other cryptographic hash functions can be use for this, **third** the benefit of this is you can access to them from your different apps as well (by using the same encryption key to decryption and accessing `keychain` store item), **at last** when you no longer need it, you can even delete it. The only thing you need to keep secret is `keychain` store key (which you used to store credentials) and also your encryption key (to used with cryptographic hash function).

There's are several libraries available to easily manipulate data in `keychain` store, [here's the one,](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXKeychain) and here's the [solution to apply MD5 or SHA1](http://www.makebetterthings.com/iphone/how-to-get-md5-and-sha1-in-objective-c-ios-sdk/).